# CDI api version mismatch error when trying to run Arquillian getting started example

Tags: cdi, jboss-arquillian, weld

I'm trying to follow the Getting started with Arquillian example here: http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/
I'am using eclipse Luna. My `pom.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.arquillian.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tutorial</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>arquillian-tutorial</name>
    <url>http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
            <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When executing the test, I end up with the following error:

```
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.IllegalStateException: WELD-000144: CDI API version mismatch. CDI 1.0 API detected on classpath. Weld requires version 1.1 or better.
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.checkApiVersion(WeldStartup.java:242)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.startContainer(WeldStartup.java:175)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startContainer(WeldBootstrap.java:69)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.startContainer(WeldBootstrap.java:64)
```

How can I fix this - preferably by using older version of Weld package as I am not able to change my development environment setup.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the following dependency into pom.xml resolved the problem:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This is just overwriting dependencies coming from another one, have a look at my answer and updated guide.

Answer (score 2):

It has been corrected in the guide already, you have to change

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

to

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
  <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
  <type>pom</type>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```